# "go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3/balancer/picker" - undefined: balancer.PickOptions

Tags: go, grpc-go

I'm getting the following error in golang

```
# go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3/balancer/picker                                                   
/home/user/go/src/go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3/balancer/picker/err.go:37:44: undefined: balancer.PickOptions                                                                              
/home/user/go/src/go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3/balancer/picker/roundrobin_balanced.go:55:54: 
undefined: balancer.PickOptions                                                              
# go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3/balancer/resolver/endpoint                                        
/home/user/go/src/go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3/balancer/resolver/endpoint/endpoint.go:114:78:
 undefined: resolver.BuildOption                                                             
/home/user/go/src/go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3/balancer/resolver/endpoint/endpoint.go:183:31:
 undefined: resolver.ResolveNowOption
```

I have tried

```
go get -u google.golang.org/grpc
```

but still getting same issue. My version of grpc is v1.26.0

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure your version is `v1.26.0`?
Can you share your `go.mod` please?

> go get -u google.golang.org/grpc

The above command is to retrieve latest version of grpc which is `v1.27.1`

Once you change the version in your `go.mod` from

```
google.golang.org/grpc v1.27.0
```

to

```
google.golang.org/grpc v1.26.0
```

you will need to run following command to lock the version:

```
go get google.golang.org/grpc@v1.26.0
```